# Integration of advertisement into WP7 apps: Any experiences?

Tags: mobile, windows-phone-7, app, admob, advertisement

Has anyone of you guys integrated or is thinking about integrating either admob, [MS pubCenter](http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2010/09/30/microsoft-advertising-opened-for-windows-phone-7-application-registrations/), [adwhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/) or any other advertising provider into your apps? Please share your experience...

1. Who pays best?
2. Any regulations?
3. Any problems with getting the app approved by Microsoft Market?
4. If you chose Admob: Which plugin do you suggest? [This](https://bitbucket.org/jacob4u2/moads/wiki/Home) or
   [that](http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2010/08/01/admob-integration-into-windows-phone-7.aspx) or another one?
5. Any experiences in Europe or Germany? (MS pubCenter is US only so
   far)

**Edit:** I think we discussed enough about acceptance of mobile advertisement. **Let's focus now on the questions I asked.**

**Edit 2:** Hmm, maybe Stackoverlfow is a better place to discuss question 2-5. Could somebody migrate this one?

Comment: An experience from the other side: I recently installed an app from Android market, discovered it downloaded and displayed ads and immediately deinstalled it. Don't want any junk on my neat gadget and certainly don't want it waste my traffic. Good luck!

Comment: Ads on Android are pretty common. I frequently use apps that provide me valuable content and I dont care about ads there. On the other hand I never have payed for any app so far. I prefer ads before buying apps. Ok, an ad-free paid app as alternative could be a solution.

Comment: @OneWorld :  if you have unlimited traffic, fine. But if not, those ad-bulked apps aren't free at all...

Comment: I think I've paid more than enough and more than reasonable for a modern smartphone, so I expect it to come with all the bells and whistles out of the box. I'm not paying for anything extra. Actually, I checked if there were free applications in the market to cover my needs before venturing into buying an Android phone.

Comment: @Joris Meys: Not sure what you mean.
@Developer Art: That is all up to you. I don't force you to download my app. However, I did a lot of server dev to publish valuable content, no other app does.

Comment: @OneWorld : Here at least you pay your internet traffic on those wireless gadgets by the Mb (30 euro for 2Gb + 0.10 euro for each extra Mb). If apps start downloading ads, that's extra traffic getting generated which you will ultimately pay for.

Comment: @Joris Meys: Ok, now I got you. Well, my app is all about downloading and presenting data from the web. The amount of traffic the ad will eat is negligible (and will never reach 2 Gb ;) I mean those folks can buy the ad free version. I personally only use Wifi and only turn on mobile web on special occasions (but not because of my fear of mobile ads;)

Comment: Oh my, how different are the views of Android mobile users compared to iPhone users. iPhone users don't mind seeing ads on valuable free apps and don't mind paying for commercial ones. I can't help but think, this must hurt the Android app market place? It's Linux all over again, i.e. the OS is open, therefore all software MUST be free! tut tut.

Comment: #Gary, I certainly didn't get an Android device to pay even more afterward. I expect free firmware updates and free apps without ads. LOTS of them!

Comment: I don't think that this is suitable for Stack Overflow - there's no coding issues involved.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.smaato.com/, http://www.aldarit.com/superads.html and http://www.millennialmedia.com/
I had the same problem and I'm currently using Smaato, for me that was the best, but you should make your own decision based on your needs.
Oh, and don't expect them to be as good as MS pubCenter, in my opinion they're not, but as for now they're all we (non US) can get.